# What is the best reference for multi-class SVM?

Tags: svm

Can someone suggest some papers about the `multi-classification` methods by `SVM`? One against all? A good survey or paper which clearly describes all of the steps.

Comment: This lecture might be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7iBpEHGVNc&t=3282s

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for multi-classification support vector machines (SVM) is the book "[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387310738)" by Bishop.

The paper "[A comparison of methods for multiclass support vector machines](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/991427/)"  by Hsu and Lin also covers the topic.